# How to run a HTML code integrated with PHP in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, html, editor

I am using HTML integrated with PHP in Visual Studio Code Editor, where the code will execute as a PHP code and the output thus delivered will be in HTML format and   I want the output(preview) for the HTML code. I have searched many sites for this integrated programming and HTML and PHP and can't find it. Help me out from this?

Answer (score 0):

File extention needs to be `.php`

Inside said file, you can start PHP with `<?php` and end it with `?>`.
Example:

```
<div>
    <?php echo("print something in php"); ?>
</div>
```

Also BTW, google could've answered this for you in 3 seconds. Next time please check google for questions that could've already been answered.